# Why is my function returning undefined along with the reversed string

Tags: javascript

Why is my `function` returning undefined along with the reversed string

```
function revString(str)
{
    var a,c;
    a=str.length-1;

    while(a>=0)
    {
       c = c + str[a];
       a--; 
    }
  return c;
}
console.log(revString("Google"));
```

I am not sure on where it is breaking. I know there are lots of answers to the same question, but i just want to understand the mistake happening here.

Below is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/c94fq78v/2/

Comment: Give `c` an initial value -- `var a, c = '';` The first time through the loop with `c = c + str[a];`, `c` hasn't yet been given a value, so it evaluates as `c = undefined + 'e';`

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assign `c` to anything at the start of your function, so it will start `undefined`.  You just need to give it an initial value:

```
function revString(str)
{
    var a,c='';
    a=str.length-1;

    while(a>=0)
    {
       c = c + str[a];
       a--; 
    }
  return c;
}
console.log(revString("Google"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the loop `c` is `undefined`. You need to initialize it to the empty string.

What happens is that adding `undefined` to the first character converts `undefined` to the string `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `c` variable